How to use DbContext in T4 template in AspnetCore .Net 8 to generate controllers?
I am trying to import my DbContext models to a T4 file, and do a looping along my models, and generate controller files for each one.
But I am getting a lot of different kind of errors like this one:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating573CA25118DE5B0FCD0076E678F0BE6ADFA63877D3EDE2048F55D299E57A2486402E96725726760F8BF9D149D7A37AAF1D1EC7A624FBAF51076B09152486A51E.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.PerformTransformation()

AVI: o log de associações de assembly está desativado.
Para ativar o log de  falhas de assembly, defina o valor do Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
Observação: há alguma penalidade para o desempenho associada ao log de falha de associação de assembly.
Para desativar esse recurso, remova o valor do Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. AtendimentoMultiTenant.T4   E:\2-PROJETOS\___SaaS\AtendimentoMultiTenant\AtendimentoMultiTenant.T4\InterfaceGenerator.tt    1

    

My Dbcontext file is like this:
namespace AtendimentoMultiTenant.Infra.ManagementArea.Context
{
    public class ManagementAreaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ManagementAreaDbContext(DbContextOptions<ManagementAreaDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContainerDb> Containers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Port> Ports { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}

My Dbcontext file is in a different project from my T4 file.
Below its my t4 code. I am trying to read my Dbcontext, but it shows me everytime a different error.
<#@ assembly name="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" #>
<#@ import namespace="AtendimentoMultiTenant.Infra.ManagementArea.Context" #>
<#@ import namespace="AtendimentoMultiTenant.T4" #>
<# 
    var dbContextType = typeof(ManagementAreaDbContext);
    var entityTypes = dbContextType.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                    p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>))
        .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
        .ToList();
#>


I have already done every kind of changes in my code to make it runs, but it only runs if I use another kind of data source, as a file for example. But I wouldlike to use my dbcontext, to be more direct to what I need to implement in my project.
I have readed that T4 do not works with Aspnetcore. Is it true ? If it isnt, how can I do this T4 file using aspnetcore in .Net 8, using EF Core 8.0 ?
Thanks.
